# MongoDB LINQ joining on collection property type's property

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following classes, which are persisted via MongoDb:

```
public class TypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TypeB> Children { get; set; }
}

public class TypeB
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
}
```

And I am joining two collections of TypeA like this:

```
IQueryable<TypeA> collection1 = GetCollection();
IQueryable<TypeA> collection2 = GetCollection();

var query = from a in collection1
            join b in collection2
                on a.Name equals b.Name
            select new { a.Name };

var list = query.ToList();
```

How can I do a similar thing but on the child property collections for the Colour property?

I've tried things along the lines of the following, but MongoDb Linq driver apparently doesn't like SelectMany statements in the join clause:

```
IQueryable<TypeA> collection1 = GetCollection();
IQueryable<TypeA> collection2 = GetCollection();

var query = from a in collection1.SelectMany(a => a.Children)
            join b in collection2.SelectMany(b => b.Children)
                on a.Colour equals b.Colour
            select new { a.Colour };

var list = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ is not a path forward for such operation since the driver won't be able to translate such syntax into MongoDB's Aggregation Framework.

The pipeline stage you need to use is [$lookup with custom pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) which allows you to specify custom "join" condition. In this case you need either [$setEquals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setEquals/index.html) or [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset). Your C# code can look like this:

```
var letDef = BsonDocument.Parse("{ colA_Children: '$Children' }");

var filter = new BsonDocumentFilterDefinition<TypeA>(BsonDocument.Parse("{ $expr: { $setEquals: [ '$$colA_Children', '$Children' ] } }"));

var pipeline = new PipelineStagePipelineDefinition<TypeA, TypeA>(
    new IPipelineStageDefinition[]
    {
        PipelineStageDefinitionBuilder.Match(filter),
    });

var fieldDef = new ExpressionFieldDefinition<AggResult, List<TypeA>>(f => f.Matched);

var results = col1.Aggregate()
    .Lookup<TypeA, TypeA, List<TypeA>, AggResult>(
        foreignCollection: col2,
        let: letDef,
        lookupPipeline: pipeline,
        @as: fieldDef
    ).ToList();
```

where:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class AggResult : TypeA
{
    public List<TypeA> Matched { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: col1.Aggregate() doesn't seem to have an overload with 0 arguments. Which overload should be used?

Comment: And why should AggResult inherit from TypeA?

Comment: @User48591 you don't need to inherit, just need to have the same fields as `TypeA` plus a list of "joined" entitites. Here's the `Aggregate` I'm using: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/7a2af91bb400ca23e2ec8cd0d14accc7b14908fa/src/MongoDB.Driver/IMongoCollectionExtensions.cs#L41

Comment: I see that the overload is on the MongoCollection and not on IQueryable interface. I also did some reading on mongodb operations to understand better what you have written. I see that the filter you've given is on the collections themselves but not on the Colour property of each child type. I want the output to be of TypeB, i.e. on the matching child

Comment: @User48591 you can change it to `{ $expr: { $setEquals: [ '$$colA_Children.Colour', '$Children.Colour' ] } }` and then the set operator will be performed on string lists instead of lists of objects but given your example it's equivalent since you have only one property. Rephrasing: `$setEquals` handles both objects and strings

Comment: Is it possible to select the elements that the matching is done on? As far as I understood setEquals compares the arrays and returns true when both sets are identical.

Given following documents:
doc1: { "Name": "doc1", "Children": [ { "Colour": "Black" }, { "Colour": "Blue" }, { "Colour": "Brown" } ] }
doc2: { "Name": "doc2", "Children": [ { "Colour": "Pink" }, { "Colour": "Blue" }, { "Colour": "Black" } ] }

I would like the query to return an array of the matching child types like so:
doc1: { "Colour": "Blue" }
doc2: { "Colour": "Black" }

Comment: I think I might have to use the $in operator instead of $setEquals and see on exactly which child the matching returned true in memory since it seems like it is not possible to return the actual result, on which the expression returned true for the matching.

Comment: @User48591 As I've mentioned you can use `setIsSubset` if you want that kind of logic